# PHP mail - special characters don't work

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
$from = "From: $email \n";
$from .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
$to = "MojaFirma@gmail.com";
$title = $_POST["typ"] . " - " . $_POST["name"];
$title = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($title) . "?=";
$tel = "";
$tel = $_POST["tel"];
if(empty($tel)) {
    $tel = "";
}
else {
    $tel = "Telefon - " . $tel . '<br/>';
}
$text = '<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head><body>';
$text .= $_POST["text"];
$text .= "<br/><br/>".$tel;
$text .= "</body></html>";
mail($to, $title, $text, $from);?>
```

[This is what i get (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upg1l.jpg)

I added charset=utf-8. My code editor coding is set to utf-8. My title has special characters but the email body doesn't have them. Please help me!

After changes (it works):

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
$from = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$from .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$from .= "From: $email" . "\r\n";
$to = "MojaFirma@gmail.com";
$title = $_POST["typ"] . " - " . $_POST["name"];
$title = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($title) . "?=";
$tel = "";
$tel = $_POST["tel"];
if(empty($tel)) {
    $tel = "";
}
else {
    $tel = "Telefon - " . $tel . '<br/>';
}
$text = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>';
$text .= $_POST["text"];
$text .= "<br/><br/>".$tel;
$text .= "</body></html>";
$text = base64_encode($text);
echo $text;
mail($to, $title, $text, $from);?>
```

Comment: This is based on value of `$_POST["text"]`. You can `var_dump($_POST["text"]);` then share the output.

Comment: I did it and got this:
string(158) "ąężźćśó

Telefon - 123 123 123
"
So it's right but the body of email isn't..

Comment: Try and encode your text to `quoted-printable` or `base64`.

Comment: quoted-printable:
=?UTF-8?B?
=C4=85=C4=99=C5=BC=C5=BA=C4=87=C5=9B=C3=B3

Telefon - 123 123 123
?=


Telefon - 123 123 123


base64:


=?UTF-8?B?PGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0L2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLTgiIC8+PC9oZWFkPjxib2R5PsSFxJnFvMW6xIfFm8OzPGJyLz48YnIvPlRlbGVmb24gLSAxMjMgMTIzIDEyMzxici8+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=?=

Comment: Nothing good happened.

Comment: When i change Content-type: text/html to Content-type: text/plain it also doesn't work

Comment: Has anybody an idea?

Comment: multibyte characters may be chunked by server software, so such text must be encoded. It is an old story about how to compose such html-mails.

Comment: Ok, so i should encode the text by quoted-printable and then put it in mail()? I did it and there was no special character, there was the encoded text.

Comment: do not forget about a `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` etc.

Comment: $from = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $from .= "Content-type: text/html; Content-Encoding: base64; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
 $from .= "From: $email" . "\r\n";

Comment: Is that code ok?

Comment: `"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"`

Comment: Ohh yees!! Thank you, it works!

Comment: @Deadooshka post your comment as an answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, if you could it would be good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [Deadooshka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3491376/deadooshka) in [its comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43436878/php-mail-special-characters-dont-work#comment73931586_43436878), you have to change the line

```
$from .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
```

to

```
$from .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
```